# Calling to a function in one page but the function needs info from another page

Tags: javascript

on page 2 im trying to have a button that updates the text of something on page 1. page 1 already has a button that updates its text with a function. im trying to use the button on page 2 to update the same text with the same function as page 1. however the function is trying to find the id of the text on page 2 however the id is on page 1. can someone look over this code and lmk what im doing wrong??
https://jsfiddle.net/ro3j9dk2/ `page2` and my java script page. https://jsfiddle.net/ro3j9dk2/1/ `page1`<- with the same javascript page

Comment: You cannot see 2 pages in one point of time :)

Comment: Actually you can, If you put 2 iframes in the same page...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612868/how-to-communicate-between-two-html-pages-via-javascript/49613963 Hope this will help you

Comment: Technically this is possible, but it involves sending data to a server, storing it and using web sockets on the second page to get the data from the server live. Otherwise, send the data to a server, then on the second page refresh the page/data (via ajax for example) every 30 seconds or whatever timeframe you choose.

Comment: You can use SharedWorker https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to make this work, but if you are opening the second window WITH the first window using window.open you can access some data from the parent window with window.parent on the second page. It would help if you explained if you were using iframes to embed the seconds page on the first page. Another alternative is using websockets to send data from one page to another. You can use websockets to send data from one client to another.